# Send data from nodejs to ejs?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Can we send data to another client ejs i's, in another server?

I tried to do:

```
res.render('/visi-web/home/www/elasticsearch/views/index.ejs',  {result:result});
```

And that's not working.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
...
res.render('/visi1-sih-web/home/www/elasticsearch/views/index.ejs',  {result:result});
});
}
});

server.listen(3333);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the formatting. - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well,you doing it wrong way.
After looking your code,When you hit '/',it load **index.ejs** 
.There is no need to give detail path.
Use following syntax.

**app.render('index', { result: 'result });**

When you set your template engine to **ejs** or something else, there is no need  to give extension.

Also ,Please check your view path is defined or not containing index.ejs.

Just give relative path for index.ejs.
means if you say

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

and within publlic folder there is **view** folder,then you should written in this way.

```
app.render('view/index', { result: 'result }).
```

No need to give `public` folder name in path.

Comment: thank you RIYAJ KHAN for your response , i can do that , but the thing is index.ejs i put it in other instance of server. not in the same project of nodejs . => server nodejs in an instance of server and client in an other instance of server like doing : server.listen(3333, 'domain2');

Comment: Is there any such need?

Comment: yeah because user can just see the client and the sever Nodejs must be in an other instance for developpers. sorry for my english and thank you again

Comment: Its very difficult to understand what you saying.Will you explain what is your requirement.I dont see any need of such

Comment: @robertklep I agree.I have just corrected his syntax.

Comment: the aim is that the servernodejs is in a server instance  and the client in another server instance that's what I was asked during my internship so I could send my data from the server to the client knowing that the customer in a server wich name is 'visi-web:3000' and in another server nodejs

Comment: Well,if you creating two server,then later it will cause cross-domain issue,remember it.Try to create on server and create two sub-folder within it.It will better one

Comment: ah ok , thank you very much  for helping maybe i'll just do all the project in one instance, thank you i feel always that i'm beginner in devloppment .